# Proof of (a step in the proof of) the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, law-of-large-numbers

**Theorem:** Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function bounded by $c$. Let $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ be i.i.d. and Uniform$(0,1)$. Then:
$$
P \left( \left\lvert \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(U_k)-\int_0^1f(x)dx \right\rvert \ge \epsilon \right) \le \frac{c^2}{n\epsilon^2}
$$

**My attempt at Proof**:
Since $U_1,...U_n$ are independent, then $f(U_i)~~ \bot ~~f(U_j)~~\forall i \neq j$. Further,the pdf of each uniform is : $f_{U_i}(t) = 1$. Thus:
$$
E_{U_1}[f(x)] = \int_{\Omega}f(x) f_{U_1}(x)dx = \int_0^1f(x)dx
$$
Also note that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le c \implies f^2(x) \le c^2$, and so: $E[f^2(x)] \le E[c^2] =c^2$ by the monotonicity of expectation. Therefore:

$$
Var (f(x)) = E[f^2(x)]-[E(f(x)]^2 \le c^2
$$

Now, letting $Y_k = f(U_k)$, then $Y_1,Y_2,...$ are independent random variables in $L^2$ with bounded variance, in that $v=sup_{k \ge 1}Var(Y_k)\le c^2 < \infty$.

By the Weak Law of Large Numbers:

\begin{align*}
P& \left( \bigg{\lvert} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(U_k)-\int_0^1f(x)dx \bigg{\rvert} \ge \epsilon \right)\\
=&P \left( \bigg{\lvert} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nY_k-E[Y_k] ~\bigg{\rvert} \ge \epsilon \right)\\
=&P \left( \bigg{\lvert} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nY_k-E[Y_1] ~\bigg{\rvert}\ge \epsilon \right)\\
&\le \frac{v}{n \epsilon^2}\\
&\le \frac{c^2}{n \epsilon^2}
\end{align*}
Where the third equality follows from the fact that $f(U_1),f(U_2),...$ all follow the same distribution. The last equality follows from the boundedness of the variance.

Does this prove the statement rigorously? Is there anything missing?

Comment: One small question - are we assuming that $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: @Math1000 the question doesn't make any more assumptions about $f$ other than the ones stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got indeed the idea, and your proof looks correct. Some comments:

- In the second line of your attempt, the expression of the p.d.f. of a uniform distribution in the unit interval is not correct if $t\notin [0,1]$.
- How do you define the random variable $f(x)$? Do you mean $f(U_1)$?
- Actually, you don't need to use the weak law of large numbers, but rather a step of its proof, namely Markov's inequality.
- I would switch the second and third lines since in the second one, it is clearer that the random variables are centered. The point is that after having applied Markov's inequality you then have to compute $\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(f(X_j))-\mathbb E[f(X_1) ]\right)^2\right]$, and if you had had $\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(f(X_j)-\mathbb E[f(X_j) ])\right)^2\right]$, this would have been neater.

Comment: you mean i should define my pdf as a piecewise function that is 0 for values outside of [0,1]?

Comment: also about switching the lines, I did that because the question suggests it should be $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ which is only true if they all have the same distribution, so I was trying to highlight that

Comment: I mean that the p.d.f. of the uniform distribution of the unit interval should be the characteristic function of the unit interval, not $1$.